# How to apply the the enter() and data() methods for ds3 in-memory data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have loaded data from a WebSocket connection into an array variable "data".  I can see the 50 elements in the array and they do have the correct map elements.

The following snippet works properly: at the end the "data" elements have all rows transformed:

```
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d[date] = parseDate(d[date]);
        d[close] = +d[close];
   });
```

Now, how to apply this data array to the internal d3 "values" so that the subsequent d3 dom manipulations use that data?  In the next snippet I have made the attempt based on the examples / blogs I had seen:

```
    var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            /* The following is NOT the correct place/way to do it.. need help here! */
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
```

**UPDATE**   Well I just tried moving those two data(data) and .enter() lines around - now placing them right after the selectAll().

```
    var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
```

The results? Well we **do** have data now !  Maybe too much of a good thing?

[image]

**EDIT**  Here is the entire function

```
function updateD3(data) {

    var WIDTH = 1800, HEIGHT = 800;


    var margin = {top: 120, right: 20, bottom: 120, left: 100},
            width = WIDTH - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = HEIGHT - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m-%d-%Y %H").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
            .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom").ticks(31);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function (d) {
                return x(d[date]);
            })
            .y(function (d) {
                return y(d[close]);
            });

    var myNode = document.body;
    while (myNode.firstChild) {
        myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
    }

    var len = data.length;
    console.log("data size=" + len + " date: " + data[0][date] + " close: " + data[0][close]
            + " last value: date: " + data[len-1][date] + " close: " + data[len-1][close]);
   var date = "CALL_HOUR";
   var close = "DROPPED_CALL";
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d[date] = parseDate(d[date]);
        d[close] = +d[close];
    });

    var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        return d[date];
    }));
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        return d[close];
    }));


    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-1.1em")
            .attr("dy", ".15em")
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "rotate(-65)"
            });

    svg.append("text")             // text label for the x axis
            .attr("x", width / 2)
            .attr("y", height + margin.bottom)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-size", "14px")
            .text("Call Date");

    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Dropped Calls");

    svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", line);

    svg.append("text")
            .attr("x", (width / 2))
            .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-size", "20px")
            .style("text-decoration", "underline")
            .text("No. of Dropped Calls vs Date Line Chart");

  }
```

Comment: By biding your data to `svg` elements, you are creating as many `svg` elements as you have data items. I suspect that is not what you want. I created this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2E78h/) exemplifying what you are doing but also showing how to bind the data to a single `g`, hopefully what you want.

Comment: why not make an answer out of this?  In your answer please copy the info from your page on fiddle and I will gladly accept In any case I have already applied it to my app.

Comment: Thanks...I posted it as an official answer.

Comment: The code you posted does not correspond to the OP and I can not figure out how to fix it to make it work.

Comment: Can you provide a Plunkr or Fiddle with some test data? It looks like your UpdateD3() function is doing too much. It should not be re-creating the parent svg element. You don't want completely destroy and recreate the D3 model every time the data changes... do you?

Comment: No I do not - you are correct in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By biding your data to `svg` elements, you are creating as many `svg` elements as you have data items. I suspect that is not what you want. I created this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2E78h/) exemplifying what you are doing but also showing how to bind the data to a single `g`.

Part of fiddle with data under a single `g`:

```
var data = [10,20,30];

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("class","oneSvg")
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height",100)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");

circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data);

circles
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("cx",function (d) {return d;})
    .attr("cy",20)
    .attr("r",5)
    .style("fill","blue");
```

Comment: Would you mind updating the variables to correspond to the elements here?  Eg. there is no "circle" element in the OP.  I am still unable to get this to work, so specifics / precision are important here.

Comment: I tried replacing "circle" with "g"  - that does not work.  I need a more careful response here, using only the elements in the OP. thanks.

Comment: Oh I am a bit confused...the fiddle in the response is the same as in the comment, and you mentioned it had helped you. I just used the circles as mock elements for some simple data. It will be easier if you generate a fiddle with your data.

Comment: I need a line chart, not circles. Can you help me to understand how to make that happen given the OP?  NOTE: I have now added the ENTIRE function .